# Install newer version of RubyGems on user directory : system-wide installation is still being used?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, installation, shared-hosting, home-directory

I have an user account on a shared Debian system that has RubyGems 1.1.1 installed and I can't make them upgrade it, at least at the moment.

I'm trying to install a new RubyGems installation locally on my home directory, following the instructions from RubyGems user guide chapter [3.2 Installing RubyGems in a User Directory](http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/3#page83).

So far, I got now latest RubyGems (1.8.10) installed at $HOME/rubygems and I have fixed the following environment variables:

- GEM_HOME to $HOME/rubygems/gems
- PATH to have $HOME/rubygems/bin before systemwide /usr/bin (which contains the old gem)

Path should be working OK, since *which gem* results as *$HOME/rubygems/bin/gem*.

Still, when I run *gem -v* I get 1.1.1.

This probably has something to do with ruby require ending up to the system-wide files of RubyGems, since the $HOME/rubygems/bin/gem starts with

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'rubygems/gem_runner'
require 'rubygems/exceptions'
```

What should I do to get my local-installed-version 1.8.10 running?

br,
Touko

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this is exactly what you want. But the easiest way would probably be to use rvm.
https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/rvm/install/

With rvm you could have your own self contained ruby environment in your home directory with exactly the tools that you need.

Comment: I had heard of RVM but was thinking that it's only for Ruby installation. But if it takes care of the whole package, including gems, that would be cool. Got to check it out.